# Why the wrap buttons block by the below components in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a view wrap many buttons and still create more buttons by textinpt contiouslly, the clode in the below, and the result now, it create new line buttons toward bottom, but will blank by textinpt components, why?, anyone know how can solve it?

My goal is auto extrusion the textinpt to move down and let it show the entire bottons.

```
const styles = {
  interests:{
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  editSection: {
      //flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  editIcon: {
    flex: 0.05,
    paddingTop: 25
  },
  input: {
    flex: 0.95
  },
  popularTag:{
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    paddingTop: 10,
  }
}

return(
  <View style = { styles.interests }>
    <View style = { styles.popularTag }>
      { this.renderShowLists() }
    </View> 
    <View style = { styles.editSection }>
      <View style = { styles.input }>
        <TextInput
          placeholder = "Type your Interests"
          onSubmitEditing = { this.onKeyPress }     
          onChangeText = { (text) => this.setState({ text }) }
          value = { this.state.text }
        /> 
      </View>
      <View style = { styles.editIcon }>
        <Icon name = "border-color" color = "#000000" size = { 20 } />  
      </View>    
    </View>
  </View>  
)
```

### The line actually are three, the second line block by textinput

[image: The line actually are three, the second line block by textinput]

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting flex value for both "popularTag" and "editSection" (also set flex value for their parent, too).

Those 2 are contained in a common same parent ("interests", which has flexDirection of *column*, so set 2 for flex), and 2 of them may have flex value of 1 for each (so that the height of both "popularTag" and "editSection" will be equal, which is 50% based on their parent - "interests" with *flex: 2*)

```
  interests:{
    flex: 2,
  },
  editSection:{
    flex: 1,
  }
  popularTag:{
    flex: 1,
  }
```

If it doesn't work yet, please post here another picture or some errors, because I didn't have time for running the all the code, thanks

Please also see my answer for another similar issue here, which is also about flexbox value, just for reference:

[Why do my react-native components overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506623/why-do-my-react-native-components-overlap/43866398#43866398)